# How to connect a single neuron in one layer with the single neuron in another layer

Tags: tensorflow, connection, sparse-matrix

I am new to Tensorflow. I want to connect a layer with another layer in which only the corresponding neurons are connected with weights to each other as shown below. This means all the neurons in the previous layer are not connected to a neuron in the next layer.

[image: Image representing the requirement]

Now I get 4 neurons with wixi. Further, I need to add all these outputs to get a single value. Now I want to pass this single value to a dense layer of size 4 for the autoencoder operation to complete.
I have created my custom layer for the wixi operation and I am correctly getting it but when I apply normal dense layer after addition I get the following error:

'''
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_15 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: [100]
'''
Following is my code for custom layer and model-

class Layer_w_x(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

```
def __init__(self):
  super(Layer_w_x, self).__init__()
def build(self, input_shape):
  self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1],), 
initializer="random_normal", trainable=True)

def call(self, inputs):
  return tf.multiply(inputs, self.w)
```

class MyModel(Model):

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
  super(MyModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  self.layer_1 = Layer_w_x()
  self.dense = Dense(4,activation = 'sigmoid')
 
  
def call(self, inputs):
  # CALCULATION FOR FIRST NEURON
  h1 = self.layer_1(inputs)
  h4 = tf.reduce_sum(h1,1)
  encoded = self.dense(h4)

  return encoded
```

model = MyModel()

output =model(my_train_data1)

my_train_data1 has size (100,4)

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own layer by subclassing from `tf.keras.layers.Layer`.
Creating custom layers is described in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models
and https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers.

I created the layer for you.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class DirectLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    
  def __init__(self):
    super(DirectLayer, self).__init__()

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.w = self.add_weight(
            shape=input_shape,
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
        )
    self.b = self.add_weight(
        shape=(input_shape[-1],), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
    )


  def call(self, inputs):
      # outputs shape 
      return tf.multiply(inputs, self.w) + self.b


layer1 = DirectLayer()
layer2 = DirectLayer()


x = tf.ones([16,2])
y = layer1(x)
y = layer2(y)

tf.print(y.shape)
```

It outputs `TensorShape([16, 2])`, which means that it maintains the input's dimensions, which, I believe, is what you want. Notice I used `tf.multiply` (multiply elementwise) as opposed to what the Dense layer does—`tf.matmul` (matrix multiplication).